# jquery sliding/timing issue

Tags: jquery, css, animation

so i'm setting up a little jquery animation where the user hovers over a container for a certain amount of time, which causes the container to split over and then reveal information inside.

i don't want the animation to begin as soon as the mouse enters the container, so I put a `delay()` on the animate. now the animation won't start right away.

however, there is an issue. if you quickly hover over the area, the animation begins and starts really fast.

here is a jsfiddle to illustrate...
http://jsfiddle.net/Rh96d/

i don't want the animation to play unless the user holds their mouse over the blue area for a certain amount of time. in this example, the animation plays even when the user removes their mouse from the area, which shouldn't happen.

sorry if i'm not being clear enough. i'm not sure how to get this to work...

Comment: Similar question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573293/jquery-time-mouse-is-over-element-hover

Comment: that's helpful and opens properly, but it still does a quick open/close if you hover over and leave the area... http://jsfiddle.net/Rh96d/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a pretty big fan of the [jQuery hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

Here's a [fiddle implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/Rh96d/7/).

After including the plugin, your script would change to

```
function hoverIn () {
    $('#one').stop().animate({marginTop:'-250px'});
    $('#two').stop().animate({marginTop:'500px'});
}
function hoverOut () {
    $('#one').stop().animate({marginTop:'0px'});
    $('#two').stop().animate({marginTop:'0px'});
}
var config = {
    over: hoverIn,
    timeout: 0,
    out: hoverOut,
    interval: 600
};

$('#main').hoverIntent(config);
```

Comment: right. the reason i'm trying to do this is so stuff isn't animating all over the page when the user is just browsing without the intention of triggering the animation.

Comment: I accidentally linked to the wrong fiddle at first, but I've fixed it. Does that accomplish what you're looking for?

Comment: yes this is what i'm trying to do. let me try and implement it.

Comment: just a quick question, how does jsfiddle know you're using the plugin? i don't see it imported anywhere on there...

Comment: it's in the `Manage Resources` section in the left nav

Answer (score 1):

Solution example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rh96d/8/

Here you are setting up a function to trigger once 500 ms has transpired. Once the mouse leaves the area the closing animation code runs.

JavaScript

```
var myTimeout;
$('#main').mouseenter(function() {
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#one').stop().delay(600).animate({marginTop:'-250px'});
        $('#two').stop().delay(600).animate({marginTop:'500px'});
        },function () {
    }, 5500);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
    $('#one').stop().animate({marginTop:'0px'});
    $('#two').stop().animate({marginTop:'0px'});
});

$('#main').mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
    $('#one').stop().animate({marginTop:'0px'});
    $('#two').stop().animate({marginTop:'0px'});
});​
```

​

Comment: moving your mouse quickly over and out of the area still causes it to open and close without waiting for the timeout...

Comment: Yes this is working. I was going to use the HoverIntent plugin but this is working without it.

Comment: Good to hear. It can probably be cleaned up. I'm working on that now.

Comment: Hmm, could there be something in here that jsfiddle is auto-correcting? it's breaking all the jquery when implemented in my site...